# Fermion propagator in terms of $\psi_{L,R}$ and $\bar{\psi}_{L,R}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, propagator

Suppose we have a fermion lagrangian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi-m\bar{\psi}\psi,
\end{equation}
which can be written in terms of $\psi_{L,R}$ and $\bar{\psi}_{L,R}$
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}_Li\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi_L+\bar{\psi}_Ri\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi_R-m(\bar{\psi}_L\psi_R+\bar{\psi}_R\psi_L).
\end{equation}

So how should I write the propagator in terms of $\psi_{L,R}$ and $\bar{\psi}_{L,R}$?
Does the propagtor contain four pieces $\langle\psi_L\bar{\psi}_L\rangle, \langle\psi_R\bar{\psi}_R\rangle, \langle\psi_R\bar{\psi}_L\rangle, \langle\psi_L\bar{\psi}_R\rangle$?

Comment: Are you asking how to write out $\langle 0|T\{\bar{\psi}(x)\psi(y)\}|0\rangle$ out in terms of $\langle 0|T\{\bar{\psi}_L(x)\psi_R(y)\}|0\rangle$ etc.?

Comment: Yes, it does. You could start by writing the propagator in terms of the 4-component spinors, which is straightforward, and expand that out in terms of left- and right-handed parts if you want.

Comment: More or less by definition the propagator should be an inverted matrix corresponding to the quadratic form (Green's function corresponding the free EOM). For massless case there si no mixing between $\psi_L$ and $\psi _R$, so in this case you'll have two independent propagators. For the massive case $\psi_L$ and $\psi _R$ talk to each other, hence the propagator is not diagonal and has (as you say yourself) four entries

Comment: @NiharKarve I want to write out the propagator of the second Lagrangian.